# What can I use to wait for all threads to be created?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

If I wanted to create 5 new threads in main and wait for all five of those threads to be created before starting the work in them, what should I use?

I found `pthread_cond_wait` and maybe that is what I should be using but I am not really sure how. Is there any way to know a thread was created and not go into that thread immediately?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need/want to wait for this?

Comment: Perhaps you want [pthread_barrier_wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_barrier_wait.3p.html) and related functions. But `pthread_thread_create` is creating a thread *immediately* so it in unclear what you really want

Comment: I need it because once the threads are created I need to do something for a specific amount of time and want all the threads to start at the same time. And I understand pthread_thread_create creates the thread immediately, but it won't create all 5 threads at the same time.

Comment: @tethys4 'want all the threads to start at the same time' is unrealistic.  Even if there are enough cores free to run all the threads, there will be some indeterminate, variable latency in dispatching them onto the cores, no matter how you make them wait or signal them to 'go'.  We are talking some small number of microseconds at best.

Comment: You don't have to wait. The very  next line after the last thread creation function will be *after* the threads are created.

Comment: PThreads are extremely useful if you learn the API, and the spirit of the API. But coming from hard RTOSes, and sometimes bare-metal, no-OS embedded systems, one really misses the detail control other APIs/OSes give you over execution. UNIX/Posix is by design best-effort, and does not usually give userspace programmers access to the scheduler to control all details of execution. But you can usually achieve what you need with mutexes and condvars, and barriers may sometimes (as in this case) useful. Also, in Linux, SCHED_DEADLINE is intended for near hard realtime needs.

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea: how would you manage the situation where a thread is not created due to some errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is a good idea what you described: how would you manage the situation where a thread is not created due to some errors?

`pthread_cond_wait` is maybe an elegant solution but you should use a wait condition for each of the 5 threads; plus a condition is more like a trigger: when something happens, do something. From what you have described you want something that is more like an initial condition.

One simple solution is to use a global variable which is a counter and everytime one of the 5 threads is created, the counter is incremented:

Anyway, to see if a thread is created correctly you can use something like this:

```
if ((err = pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, threadFunction, NULL))!=0)
{
    printf("some error\n");
}
else
{
    global_counter++;
}
```

Then in each of the thread functions, use a loop that does nothing and whose loop condition checks if the counter variable is less than the number of threads you want to create:

```
while (global_counter<5)
{
    ;
}
..../rest of the thread functions
```

NOTE: it is dangerous because if you are not careful in choosing the variable values you get stuck in 5 infinite loops.

Also you should use some type of mutex (read/write mutex maybe) since the global counter is written by one thread and read by many.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: Also you should manage the situation when one of the threads is not created (for example killing the already created threads and not creating the others) otherwise the others will be stuck again in that infinite loop.

**EDIT 2**

I know this was asked a long time ago but actually there are also other solutions, maybe more elegant.

One is the one sited in your question using `pthread_cond_wait()` in the thread that must wait for an initialization and `pthread_cond_broadcoast()`/`pthread_cond_signal()` in the initialization thread.

The difference between `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_broadcast` is the following: in the former a single thread will acquire the lock and execute. The others still have to wait. With `pthread_cond_broadcast` all threads will be unblocked simultaneously. For example:

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_cond_t  cv;

void* threadFunction(void*);

int main()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    if ((err = pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, threadFunction, NULL))!=0)
    {
       printf("some error\n");
    }
  }
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}

void* threadFunction(void*)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);
  do_things();
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

Another solution in my opinion is to use write-lock and write lock: at the beginning the `main thread` lock a read-write mutex on write. Other threads will try it to lock it (for example in read mode if you want to wake them up simultaneously) but there being a write lock they will be blocked.

When all threads are created the `main` unlock and the others can execute:

```
pthread_rwlock_t lock; 

void* threadFunction(void*);

int main()
{
  pthread_rwlock_init(&lock, ...);
  //First acquire the write lock:
  if ((res = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock)!=0)
  {
      exit(1);
  } 
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    if ((err = pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, threadFunction, NULL))!=0)
    {
       printf("some error\n");
    }
  }
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
  pthread_rwlock_destroy(&lock);
  }

void* threadFunction(void*)
{
  pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);
  do_things();
  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
}
```